# How do I get an item in a List<> based on an integer field?

Tags: c#, generics, list

I have a List<> in my program, filled with my custom class. I want to be able to extract an object from the list by simply specifying an integer, then returning all objects that have an integer property set to that integer. I was thinking of doing it like this:

```
int exampleint = 5;
List<MyClass> extract = new List<MyClass>();
for(int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++) {
    if(list[i].Number == exampleint)
        extract.Add(list[i]);
}
return extract;
```

Is there any better or faster way do do this? Just wondering.

Update: Chris, your answer was a little off. This:

```
 List<MyClass> extract = list.FindAll(delegate(int obj) { return obj.Number == exampleint; });
```

should in fact be this:

```
List<MyClass> extract = list.FindAll(new Predicate<MyClass>(delegate(MyClass obj) { return obj.Number == exampleint; }));
```

Your first example gave me errors. But thanks for pointing me in the right direction, it seems to work now.

Comment: Can you use Linq in this project?

Comment: Glad I could help. That's odd, because I've been using and compiling the way I suggested for over a year without problems. Just ran it through Visual Studio, and it didn't complain. Well, ReSharper complains, telling me to convert it to a lambda, but it compiles just fine with the delegate version.

Comment: One of the errors I realized on my own was the "obj.Number" part. There is no member named Number in an Int32.

Comment: configurator pointed that out in a response to my comment. My first example using lambdas auto-detects the type. The second one I fired off without testing, and you're right, it should be a MyClass. I've corrected it below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
List<MyClass> extract = list.FindAll(obj => obj.Number == exampleint);
```

OR (if you're using .NET 2.0 and can't use expressions)

```
List<MyClass> extract = list.FindAll(delegate(MyClass obj) { return obj.Number == exampleint; });
```

Comment: +! That's more elegant than mine :)  I always forget about FindAll.

Comment: Thank you! I'm using 2.0, probably should have said that.

Comment: configurator is correct. For the first example, .NET will auto-detect the type, but the second one should've been MyClass.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have C#2, try this:

```
public delegate bool Predicate<T>(T item);

public static IEnumerable<T> Where(IEnumerable<T> source, Predicate pred)
{
    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        if (pred(item))
            yield return item;
    }
}
```

You can reuse that whenever you have this kind of filtering requirement, like this:

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> filtered = Where(list, delegate(MyClass c) { return c.Number == exampleint; });
```

It's essentially identical to the Linq solutions and it will enable you to get use to this style of list processing ready for when you can upgrade your compiler.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C# 3:

`return (from e in list
        where e.Number == exampleint
        select e).ToList();`

This will run a LINQ query that pulls them out, then converts to a list.  If you can return IEnumerable instead, you can avoid the ToList() call.

Answer (score 0):

Use Linq/extension methods:

```
var result = list.Where(x => x.PropertyValue == YourSelectedValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Linq:

List extract = existingList.Where(x => x.Number == exampleInt).ToList();